# Border two vertically aligned subfigures

Tags: subfloats, border

I have two vertically aligned subfigures as follows and it works well:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\subfigure[a]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image1}}\\ 
\subfigure[b]{
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image2}}

\caption{caption1}
\label{lable1}
\end{figure}
```

However when I am trying to put a border to both of them using `\fbox` or `\frame` the new line command `\\` returns an error! If I remove it there will be no error but the subfigures do not align vertically anymore.

How can I have both vertical alignment for the figures and a border surrounding both of them at the same time?

Comment: For one thing, the \fbox is bigger than the subfigures, one of which is at least \textwidth wide.

Comment: BTW, which subfigure package are you using?  There are many, and most of them are obsolete.

Comment: I use MikTex 2.9 which takes care of downloading the packages automatically and I use this command '\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}' to include subfigure commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two different ways to handle `\\` inside a `\fbox`, depending on whether you know the width needed.  Actually, with the tabular you don't even need `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\hfil\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% maximum allowed
\centering
\subfigure[a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\\ 
\subfigure[b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{caption1}
\label{lable1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\hfil\begin{tabular}{|c|}% width unknown
\hline
\subfigure[a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\\ 
\subfigure[b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption2}
\label{lable2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution with the `framed` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{framed}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.65\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ernst_vierge}
        \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vskip 4ex

        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{framed}
    \caption{caption1}
    \label{lable1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One more alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
                \end{minipage}}
    \caption{caption1}
\label{lable1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Package `subfigure` is considered obsolete and replaced with `subfig`. However, I suggest to use more advanced `subcaption` and its environment `subfigure`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `tcolorbox` was missing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\centering
\subfigure[a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\\ 
\subfigure[b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\caption{caption1}
\label{lable1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Approved :-)